# Some questions about C++ header file references when programming ROS2humble

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This header file always fails to be referenced:

```
#include "tutorial_interfaces/msg/num.hpp"
```

I don’t know why. I am learning humble from Foxy’s tutorial. Is it because of version differences?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417883/some-questions-about-c++-header-file-references-when-programming-ros2humble/) by [xudadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/166967/xudadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2023-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Correct. In my install of Humble there is no 'tutorial_interfaces". In my Humble there is "example_interfaces" but there is no "num.hpp" there.

Assuming you're on linux, the msg files can be found here `/opt/ros/humble`

I suggest you find the Humble version of what you're trying to do,, if it exists.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2023-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xudadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/166967/xudadi/) on 2023-07-30**:
yes, on linux, and I'm a beginner and I didn't find a better humble tutorial